# Library multiple linking and binary duplication?

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

Here is a basic question (so possibly dup, but so far I couldn't find an appropriate answer, even in [How does the compilation/linking process work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work)) regarding library linking in `C`++ and possible specificity when using CMake.

How the binary of a given library is managed when it appears multiple times in the dependency graph of an application (in a diamond-like pattern)?

Let `A` and `B` be two libraries, `C` an application.

`A` depends on `B`

`C` depends on `A` but also on `B` directly (symbols of `B` are mentioned in `C` code)

My question breaks down as follow

1-      `A` is exposing symbols from `B` (symbols of `B` are mentioned in `A` interface)

a.       Without cmake

If I compile `C` with `-l A -l B` and `A` with `-l B`: how many copies of `B` binaries will there be in `C`?

Does the nature of `A` and `B` changes the answer (according to `A` and `B` being dynamic or not, thus giving 4 possibilities)

b.       With cmake

Same question but instead of `-l` I'm doing `find_package` followed by `target_link_libraries`.
(`A` and `B` are supposedly properly packaged and installed, in order to be found by `find_package`)

`C` is including `A` and `B` as `PRIVATE`

`A` is including `B` as `PUBLIC`

2-      `A` is not exposing `B`

a.       Without cmake

If I compile `C` with `-l A -l B` and `A` with `-l B`: how many copies of `B` binaries will there be in `C`?

Does the nature of `A` and `B` changes the answer (according to `A` and `B` being dynamic or not, thus giving 4 possibilities)

b.       With cmake

Same question but instead of `-l` I'm doing `find_package` followed by `target_link_libraries`

`C` is including `A` and `B` as `PRIVATE`

`A` is including `B` as `PRIVATE`

[EDIT] additional context
The question arose in embedded context where it was debated between using shared or static library. In the diamond inclusion situation, we feared a useless increase of the binaries size on the system and wanted a more generic answer than "try it on some device, hope it will be the same behavior everywhere".

Comment: "Here is a basic question" - Here are **several questions** in the single question post. That by itself is discouraged by Stack Overflow. Some of those questions are non-CMake ones. Others are CMake ones, but lacks for **complete code**, without which one hardly understand them. Have you tried to find answers to your questions **one by one**?

Comment: Actually I think that all the sub-questions, in fine are related to the same topic: how are diamond-like dependencies managed. Direct linkage or usage of the CMake layer may change the answer and, IMHO, it would be interesting for the reader to have all the alternatives within a single post. Thus my "violation" of SO rule for *single question post*  that I reinterpreted as *single topic post*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't see either, how to propose a code will be helpful in this particular case. And yes, I look up for an answer for individual sub-questions but  without success (I generally find quite generic info such as in the linked post). Any other idea to improve the question? Do you disagree with the *single question*/*single topic argument*?

Comment: A dynamic library will link the libraries it relies on, so that definitely makes a difference.  You could easily end up with multiple copies of a library.  What's worst is if there are static variables, you'll get multiple copies that aren't connected in any way.

Comment: "how are diamond-like dependencies managed" - This topic is **too broad** for Stack Overflow either.

Answer (score 1):

You're right to be concerned.  I had a bad experience with this in Windows many years ago.  I'm not certain your embedded system will work the same, but the principles are probably similar.

If all your libraries are static or all dynamic, you probably won't have a problem.

But if you have a dynamic library that relies on a static library, that static library will be linked into the dynamic one.  If another dynamic library needs that same static library, it will get a copy too.  And the application will get its own copy.

In my case we had singletons in the static libraries that used static variables to ensure singleness.  Since there were multiple copies of the library, there were multiple copies of the variable, and the singletons were not so single anymore.  Chaos ensued.

Comment: Thx. Besides, I see an additional layer of complexity on windows where symbols of a shared library may or may not be exported... Anyway, does C++ specifies things on the linkers? For instance, do they examine linked libraries to see if they provide the same symbols and thus ignore one of the link (the direct link to ```B``` in my example. It could also work with shared libraries as, AFAIK, they are coming with a stub static library that declare available symbols.

Comment: @Oersted I don't think the standard talks about linkers at all; that's an implementation detail.  The closest it gets is specifying symbol linkage properties.  I think if the same symbol is available from different libraries, the linker will just use the first one it finds.

Comment: may be you could improve your answer for the record. ASFAIK, if a static lib depends on another one, the second one binary is not included anyway in the first one. For shared library, they behave a bit like an application, as it must embed its static dependencies, leading to the problem you mentioned. Yet I lack references from linker documentation for instance. Reasoning this way, I can't see how cmake could prevent the dup (the shared lib may not export all the symbols from the static one, so the direct link to the static cannot be discarded).